# make a method globally available in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In several Vue files this computed property checks if `this.data` is not an empty object:

```
computed: {
     isLoaded() {
         return !(this.data && Object.keys(this.data).length === 0 && this.data.constructor === Object);    // checks if this.data is not empty
     }
 }
```

Then `isLoaded` is used to conditionally display content in the browser.

I'd like to refactor the code and create a global method somehow that can check if an object is empty so  all the files that use this method can get it from a central spot.

Even after doing some reading on Vue mixins and plugins I'm not clear which one best fits this use case.  Which one should be used for this?  Or is there an altogether different approach that would be better to create a global method?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it and it and approach depends on particular case. For your case I'd suggest you to create a separate folder for utils functions, where you could have smth like `common.js`. There you can just export your functions e.g.

```
export const emptyObj = (obj: any): any => Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
```

and import it in your component:

```
import { emptyObj } from "src/utils/common";
```

In this case it easier to organize your shared functions, easier to test them and have typescript support.

Comment: Is there a global approach that would avoid adding the `import` line into each component that needs it?

Comment: Yes, you can create global Mixin that will be running on every vue component (might be an overhead) or you can add this function to Vue.prototype. See the dock https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin

Comment: Btw, check out v-cloak, it's built in Vue directive which does similar thing that you're doing
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak